# React/JS mouse event handlers not working like I would expect it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

Lets say I have an app like:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onMouseDown={(e) => console.log("down")}
        onMouseUp={(e) => console.log("up")}
        onMouseMove={(e) => console.log("move")}
      >
        test
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

With this minimal example I would expect that *down* is fired only once when pressing the mousebutton, *up* also once etc. But my console output shows that things seem to get messy when also moving the mouse? What is going on here? like real input is mousedown->mousemove->mouseup but console is sth like mousedown->mousemove->mouseup->mousedown->mousemove->mouseup which makes no sense to me....

Thanks a lot!

it does not matter if it's an button or not (I just choose a button for simplicity).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const handleEvent = (e) => {
        if (e.type === "mousedown") {
            console.log('mouse down')
        } else if (e.type === "mouseup") {
            console.log('mouse up')
        } else if (e.type === "mouseleave") {
            console.log('mouse leave')

        }
return (<div>
                           <button
                            onMouseLeave={(e)=> handleEvent(e)}
                            onMouseMove={(e)=> handleEvent(e)}
                            onMouseUp={(e)=> handleEvent(e)}
                            onMouseDown={(e)=> handleEvent(e)}>
                               test
                            </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but also with this solution "random" mousedown events get fired when I move the mouse (after the real existing mousedown event...)

Comment: Do you want to get the event only once when you leave the mouse?

Comment: Actually I don't need the mouse leave event, I just need an event when mousedown is happening, then I need the mousemove events and then finally the mouseup event... I try to implement some drag and drop behavior for some react-svg (dont want to add a dependency for this simpe(?) task...)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my mouse, and now it works!

It seems like my wireless mouse somehow lost connection which triggered a `mouseup` event. And when the connection was there again, a `mousedown` event triggered again...

Four hours of headache got solved!